# Script to switch primary display setting

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, powershell, script, display-settings

Given an extended 2-display setup, is there a script (Powershell preferred) that will toggle the following setting for a display?

[image: change primary display option]

Under different circumstances, I'd like to set my laptop or my monitor as the primary display of the extended setup. I'm fine with 2 separate scripts sitting on my desktop each toggling a single display's primary status.

Comment: consider https://sourceforge.net/projects/monitorswitcher/

Comment: TechSultan - I have a method that'll do this with AutoIT which is a free scripting language that you can use without installing it too. If you would consider such a solution, hit me back and give me your approval and I'll be happy to add the detail as an answer. I've tried a few other solutions working with WinAPI and another with VBS and couldn't get it—I'm sure it's possible somehow though, but the AutoIT solution worked for me without tons of effort; just simple scripting.

Comment: We should be able to control this via registry but I'm unable to find where this information is stored.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) of Nir Sofer: command line arguments "/SetPrimary 2" will set monitor #2 as primary.